# How to give tooltip in extjs 4.2.1 for rowexpander icon on mouse over?

Tags: java, javascript, extjs4.2

How to give tooltip for rowexpander icon in extjs 4.2.1?.
I am using row expander plugins and want to give tooltip if + icon then Expand All ,if - then Collapse All dynamically.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How did it work out (or not)?

Comment: I have tried using css to add data-qtip attribute to that div element and also tried to add attr(title) ,attr(data-qtip) to x-grid-row-expander  css class. After that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> **Use this in the Grid Listeners which has Row Expander Plugin.**

```
afterlayout : function (obj) {
                if (obj.view.getNodes().length > 0) {
                    var nodes = obj.view.getNodes();
                    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                        var rowNode = nodes[i],
                        row = Ext.fly(rowNode, '_rowExpander'),
                        isCollapsed = row.hasCls('x-grid-row-collapsed');
                        if (isCollapsed)
                            Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('div.x-grid-row-expander', nodes[i]).title = "Expand record";
                        else
                            Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('div.x-grid-row-expander', nodes[i]).title = "Collapse Record";
                    }
                }
            }
```